# validate date format DDMMYYYYHHMMSS in java?

Tags: java, date

I am getting date  like `DDMMYYYYHHMMSS`.

I want to check weather it is valid `date` format.

How can I do so?

Comment: For validation date should be in Correct format.

Comment: More to the point, have you tried reading the javadocs for `SimpleDateFormat` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code

```
public static boolean isValidDate(String inDate) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    dateFormat.setLenient(false);
    try {
        dateFormat.parse(inDate.trim());
    } catch (ParseException pe) {
          return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Change the format according to your need. Check this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

Pass Any Valid Date Format and check if the date is valid or not

```
public boolean isThisDateValid(String dateToValidate, String dateFromat){

    if(dateToValidate == null){
        return false;
    }

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFromat);
    sdf.setLenient(false);

    try {

        //if not valid, it will throw ParseException
        Date date = sdf.parse(dateToValidate);
        System.out.println(date);

    } catch (ParseException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```